# Escape closed parenthesis in elixir sigil

Tags: elixir, sigils

I want to have a custom sigil, so that i can have one element per line.

This is code i have

```
def sigil_l(text,[]), do: String.split(text,"\n")
```

This works fine for

```
~l(Clash of Titans
   The day after Tomorrow
   The Transporter
 )
```

This fails for

```
~l(The man from Earth (2007)
   Gone Girl (2014)
   )
```

*Notice the brackets above*

This is the error message

```
"{" starting at line 38 is missing terminator "}". Unexpected token: )
(elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:97: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8
```

The Expected outcome is

```
["The man from Earth (2007)",
"Gone Girl (2014)"]
```

What code needs to be changed.
Do i need to add any characters in input as well and handle in sigil defination ?

**Update**

The solution that @AbM gave is correct.
I was on elixir version 1.0.4 so it did not work. It does works on 1.1.x

Solution

```
~l(The man from Earth (2007\)
   Gone Girl (2014\)
   )
```

Comment: You should change your question.  You're trying to escape a close parenthesis not a bracket.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Appreciate your suggestion. Changed question title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should escape the closing parenthesis with `\)`:

```
~l(The man from Earth (2007\)
   Gone Girl (2014\)
)
```

Here's my script and iex output:

```
defmodule SigilL do

  def sigil_l(text,[]), do: String.split(text,"\n")

end
```

[image]

Comment: No, this is the output with suggested change.
"The man from Earth (2007\\)     Gone Girl (2014\\)"

Comment: Works for me. Added the `iex` output

Comment: What wrong am i doing.

`    iex(1)> defmodule Foo do`
    ...(1)>   def sigil_l(text,[]), do: String.split(text,"\n")
    ...(1)> end  
        {:module, Foo,
     <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 4, 252, 66, 69, 65, 77, 69, 120, 68, 99, 0, 0, 0, 137, 131, 104, 2, 100, 0, 14, 101, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 95, 100, 111, 99, 115, 95, 118, 49, 108, 0, 0, 0, 2, 104, 2, ...>>,
 {:sigil_l, 2}}  
    iex(2)> import Foo
    nil  
    iex(3)> ~l(The man from Earth (2007\)  
    ...(3)>    Gone Girl (2014\)  
    ...(3)> )  
    ["The man from Earth (2007\\)", "   Gone Girl (2014\\)", ""]  
    iex(4)>

Comment: You are correct. It did not work with me as I had elixir version 1.0.4. Upgraded to Elixir 1.1.1 and it works. Thanks for posting complete shell picture, It gave a clue to upgrade version.

Answer (score 1):

There are also a variety of delimiters for sigils.
So instead of:

```
~s(My funky "string(\)")
```

You can also use:

```
~s|My funky "string()"|
```

Which avoids the use of a forward slash. 
Obviously, that means you'll have to find another delimiter for:

```
~s|My funky "string(|)"|
```

But at least there's a solution available for that.
https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/sigils/